# Cannot invoke set Double(Double) on the primitive type double

Tags: java, arrays, double, jlist

I have a JList with a bunch of names in it, and an array for the value of those names

```
final Double[] filmcost = { 5.00, 5.50, 7.00, 6.00, 5.00 };
```

What I want to do is when someone selects something from the list, it assigns the value to a variable (it also sets a text box to a string from another array, but that works fine).

So I've got my variable

```
protected double filmCost;
```

and here's the ListSelectionListener

```
filmList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt) {
                                                    filmCost.setDouble(filmcost[filmList.getSelectedIndex()]);
            }
        });
```

However, it's complaining that it "Cannot invoke set Double(Double) on the primitive type double". I feel like the solution is really simple, but I've been stuck on this for over an hour now.

Answer (score 5):

A `double` is just a primitive value with no methods, just assign it.

```
filmCost = filmcost[filmList.getSelectedIndex()];
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need is to write it like this :

```
filmList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
       public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent evt) {
             filmCost = filmcost[filmList.getSelectedIndex()];
       }
 });
```

Because `filmCost` is double primitive and you cannot invoke any methods on primitive( they are not objects on which you call `set` , `get` or any method). So simply assign the value using `=`.

Also an advice, change the variable names `filmCost` and `filmcost` because they are quite confusing (they appear identical, atleast I got confused at my first look).

Comment: Thanks, that was so simple I feel stupid (I even assigned stuff earlier like that). And yes, I could probably name my variables better. I used to call them random vegetable names at one point though...

Comment: @p3tch I was impressed by `can't actually share much of the code without being done for academic misconduct` good spirit